# How to configure Apache Camel to print trace id and span id and pass to different routes

Tags: spring, apache-camel

> INFO [service,00000000000000000000000000000000,0000000000000000] 476 --- [14 - Aggregator] eamRoute                              : Total time taken for batch insertion: 0 seconds
> INFO [payment-service,00000000000000000000000000000000,0000000000000000] 476 --- [ormAndSendRoute] message-producer                    : Request body sending to API:

**I am using opentelemetry apache camel(4.1.0)
Dependencies added**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-opentelemetry-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml configuration: mdc is enabled.

```
  springboot:
    main-run-controller: true
    use-mdc-logging: true
    mdc-logging-keys-pattern: "*"

logging:
  file:
    name: '${logging.file.path}/app.log'
    path: ./logs
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{trace_id:-},%X{span_id:-}]"
```

spring boot java class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @CamelOpenTelemetry
    public class TraceIdApplication {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TraceIdApplication.class, args);
     }
   }

   @Component
   public class CamelTraceId extends RouteBuilder  {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=2000")
                .log("in timer")
                .to("direct:traceLogging")
                .end();

        from("direct:traceLogging")
                .to("direct:restfulcall")
                .log("testing").end();
   }
```

when those two routes are called need to print the trace id and span id.

Comment: If you're on the same thread a simple `MDC.get("trace_id")` should give you the value. AFAIK this is set and removed via Camel's [ActiveSpanManager](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/9ae218b5e4422166142cef85a48d368cd00398c0/components/camel-tracing/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/tracing/ActiveSpanManager.java) which is further used by [OpenTelmetryTracingStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/9ae218b5e4422166142cef85a48d368cd00398c0/components/camel-opentelemetry/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/opentelemetry/OpenTelemetryTracingStrategy.java).

Comment: @RomanVottner, thanks for looking into this query. I have tried based on the Apache Camel document, https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/others/opentelemetry.html, just adding the dependency, annotating **CamelOpenTelemetry** and enabling the MDC should suffice right? But wondering why it is not working. By the way I tried MDC.get("trace_id"). I am getting null on the same thread.

Comment: Did you call MDC from inside Camel beans or processors? You could also try to call `SpanAdapter span = ActiveSpanManager.getSpan(currExchange); if (span != null) { log.debug("span_id: {}, trace_Id: {}", span.spanId(), span.traceId()); }` which should return the active span that should be present in the exchange property.

Comment: @RomanVottner Thanks. Yes I have called. I have tried with your code, it's printing all zero's span_id: 0000000000000000, trace_Id: 00000000000000000000000000000000... from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=2000")
                .log("Timer called...")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    SpanAdapter span = ActiveSpanManager.getSpan(exchange);
                    if (span != null) { log.info("span_id: {}, trace_Id: {}", span.spanId(), span.traceId()); }
                })

Comment: This matches the output you see in your MDC logs. I guess it behaves similar to AWS XRay by collecting span records in a local agent which then sends those spans to the respective tracing service. Not sure at which point here the respective span and traceIds are created. You can try in a test case to send in multiple messages that pass through the exchanges to see whether here span and trace IDs change or not. I never worked with OpenElementry before, so can't give any insights into that

Comment: @RomanVottner, I don't have to use specifically openTelemetery as requirement, if there is any other working example that gives me the traceid and spanid is good. Appreciate if you have any other working example like Apache Camel Micrometer is fine.